# Is an inextensible manifold necessarily compact?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a connected $n$ dimensional boundary-less smooth manifold with the property that for any connected boundary-less $n$ dimensional manifold $\overline{M}$ and any embedding $i:M\rightarrow \overline{M}$, we must have $\overline{M}=i[M]$.

Question: Must $M$ be compact ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, $M$ must be compact.  In fact, if $M$ is non-compact, it admits a non-surjective self embedding $f:M\rightarrow M$.

When $n=1$, the only non-compact manifold is $\mathbb{R}$, which obviously admits non-surjective self-embeddings.  So we assume $n=2$.

We will first construct $f$ for the special case where $M = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\lambda:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ denote a smooth bump function which is identically $1$ near $0$, and also supported near $0$, and let $\mu:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-\infty, 0)$ denote any diffeomorphism which is the identity on $(-\infty,-1)$.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$f(x_1,x_2,\dotsc, x_n) = \left(\lambda\left(\sum_{i=2}^n x_i^2\right) \mu(x_1) + \left(1-\lambda\left(\sum_{i=2}^n x_i^2\right)\right)x_1, x_2,\dotsc,x_n\right).$$  One easily verifies that $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, which is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a neighborhood of the non-negative $x_1$-axis removed.  We note for later that $f$ is the identity as long as $\sum_{i=2}^n x_i^2$ is large enough, or if $x_1\leq -1$.

Now, we promote this to a construction on a general non-compact $n$-dimensional manifold.

To that end, select a curve $\gamma:[0,\infty)\rightarrow M$ with closed image.  For example, one could put a complete metric on $M$ and then choose $\gamma$ to be a geodesic ray.  Then $\gamma$ has a neighborhood $V$ for which the pair $(V,\gamma([0,\infty)))$ is diffeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n, \{(x,0.\dotsc,0): x\geq 0\})$.

Using the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case, we can now self-embed $V$ into itself in a non-surjective fashion.  Extending this map to the rest of $M$ using the identity completes the construction.

Comment: I guess $\gamma$ should be an injective curve?

Comment: @LSpice:  Yes, sorry, it should be embedded with closed image.

Comment: Here's a picture for the image of $f$ with $n=3$. Think of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a ball of clay. Stick your finger in it, pushing towards the center. I learned of these kind of a self diffeomorphisms ages ago from an MO or MSE question about non-compact n-manifolds deformation retracting onto smaller dimensional sub-complexes.

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434867/is-an-inextensible-manifold-necessarily-compact/434881#comment1120286_434881)!  Since @DmitryK [says](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434867/is-an-inextensible-manifold-necessarily-compact/434881#comment1120280_434877) that they will delete their answer, I'll probably just let it be, but I appreciate your keeping track.